# Choosing particular values from a Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the Pandas Series `s`, part of which can be seen below. I basically want to insert the indices of those values of `s` which are not 0 into a list `l`, but don't know how to do this.

```
2003-05-13      1
2003-11-2       0
2004-05-1       3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [7] is what you're looking for below:

```
In [5]: s = pd.Series(np.random.choice([0,1,2], 10))

In [6]: print s
0    0
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    2
9    2
dtype: int64

In [7]: print list(s.index[s != 0])
[1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```